# Trouble with saving a 4D array to file

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some code that does not seem to operate the way it should. The whole point is to take a 256x128x256x2 array of integers, split it into 256 16x128x16x2 chunks, process the chunks into a byte array, then add that byte array to a main array of bytes to be saved. `chunkdata[]` is fine before saving, but after saving the whole file is blank except the first 4096 bytes. the location table (location of each chunk in the file) is there and the first four byte "chunk header" is there, everything else is 0's, which isn't supposed to happen.

```
public void createFile(int[][][][] map){
    byte[] file = new byte[fileLength]; //22,024,192 bytes long
    System.arraycopy(Sector.locationTable, 0, file, 0, Sector.locationTable.length); //This works as it should
    for(int cx = 0; cx < 16; cx++)
    {
        for(int cz = 0; cz < 16; cz++)
        {
            int start = sectorLength+cx*(sectorLength*chunkSectorLength)+cz*(chunkRows*sectorLength*chunkSectorLength); //this algorithm works, just rather hideous 
            int[][][][] chunk = getChunk(map, cx * 16, cz * 16); //This works as it should
            byte[] chunkdata = putChunk(chunk); //The data from this is correct

            int counter = 0;
            for(int i=start;i<chunkdata.length;i++){
                file[i]=chunkdata[counter]; //Data loss here?
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Saving file...");
    writeFile(file, fileLocation);
}

public static void writeFile(byte[] file,String filename){
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        fos.write(file);
        fos.close();
        Messages.showSuccessfulSave();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Messages.showFileSavingError(ex);
    }
}
```

So, assuming putChunk and getChunk work as intended, and my hideous algorithms, what could cause everything past the first 4096 bytes to be blank?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it was loss of data. If, for example, x=16 and z=32, it returns a large array of 0's for some reason.

Comment: This looks like it should work. Are you sure the problem isn't elsewhere or in the data?

Comment: Not entirely sure to be honest. I know the data is right since I periodically have it print out small samples after it's done formatting it. What I'm trying to do in hole is split the data into 16x128x16x2 chunks of elements, process it into a byte[] array with some other data, then save it to a file. The data in the byte array's is correct, but the save data is all 0's past the first chunk's header. I'll update the post with the most probable problematic piece other than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you comparing `i` against `chunkdata.length` when `i` is initialized with `start`? I think `counter` should be used instead.

Current:

```
   int counter = 0;
   for(int i=start;i<chunkdata.length;i++){
      file[i]=chunkdata[counter]; //Data loss here?
      counter++;
   }
```

Instead, you want to write something like this:

```
   int counter = 0;
   for(int i=start;counter<chunkdata.length;i++){
       file[i]=chunkdata[counter]; //Data loss here?
       counter++;
   }
```

or more compact way:

```
   for(int i=start,counter = 0;counter<chunkdata.length;i++,counter++){
       file[i]=chunkdata[counter]; //Data loss here?
   }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! After checking the file in a hex editor, it saved correctly. I guess I overlooked that loop too much to notice the problem!

Comment: Good to know that it worked. Sometimes you need a second pair of eyes to locate a very trivial issue :)